# Win8 RT Metro Style App HTTP Response Async?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a C# app that I created for my home automation system in WPF.
I would like to convert it to a win8 Modern UI app just for fun.
I am not a programmer or even close...so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my old code to check the status of one of the devices.  The following just checks the status code for a light.  1 means the light is turn on... 0 it is off.

```
        //InitializeComponent();
        WebRequest MasterbedRoomrequest = WebRequest.Create("http://10.10.1.100:3480/data_request?id=lu_variableget&serviceId=urn:upnp-org:serviceId:SwitchPower1&Variable=Status&DeviceNum=7");
        HttpWebResponse MasterbedRoomWebresponse = (HttpWebResponse)MasterbedRoomrequest.GetResponse();
        Stream MasterbedRoomdataStream = MasterbedRoomWebresponse.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader readerMasterBedRoom = new StreamReader(MasterbedRoomdataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServerMasterbedRoomdata = readerMasterBedRoom.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.
        //Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        if (responseFromServerMasterbedRoomdata == "1")
        {
            MasterBedRoomLamp.Checked = true;
        }
        // Cleanup the streams and the response.
        readerMasterBedRoom.Close();
        MasterbedRoomdataStream.Close();
        MasterbedRoomWebresponse.Close();
```

I would like to do the same in a Modern UI application.  From what I am reading on the web...it seems like the recommended method to do this is by using the ASYNC capabilities of HTTP?  The above code doesn't work when I throw it into one of the modern UI VS templates and attempt to compile.

I have seen several examples but they all seem to be more complicated than I would expect it to be.

Question.  What is the most straight forward way to do the above task?  The shorter the better.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: "I am not a programmer or even close...so any pointers would be greatly appreciated." I am afraid that you don't get how funny this is. There are very few starting programmer who like pointers.

Comment: HA!  Next time I will leave out the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be a little different.

```
public async Task<bool> IsLampOn(){
    string responseData = await GetDataFromUrl("http://10.10.1.100:3480/data_request?id=lu_variableget&serviceId=urn:upnp-org:serviceId:SwitchPower1&Variable=Status&DeviceNum=7");
    return (responseData == "1")
}

public async Task<string> GetDataFromUrl(string url){
    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await(http.GetAsync(new Uri(url)));
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Essentially, you'll just call

```
bool val = await IsLampOn();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Julian!  I appreciate you taking the time to write that example out.  It looks like it will do the trick for me!  I get a weird message when calling islampon but I will figure it out.  Thanks again.

Comment: No problem; let me know if you need any additional help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [HttpClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28VS.110%29.aspx). Here is a [simple example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HttpClient-sample-55700664).  You can avoid the stream work with [GetStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync.aspx).

Comment: Thank you.  I had seen that example but was unable to totally follow it.  it appears that scenario 1 best matches what I am trying to do.  I still don't totally get it.  Shouldn't you be able to do the above in about 3 - 5 lines of code?  Without all the error handling etc...  The example seems to be doing a Uri.TryCreate to the url and something like this for the reponse.    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(resourceUri);

                await Helpers.DisplayTextResult(response, OutputField);  I am not getting anywhere unfortunately.